# Show enum values once with ng-repeat and merge values from json

Tags: angularjs, json, checkbox, enums, angularjs-ng-repeat

JSON

```
{
    "SubQuestion": "A question",
    "AnswerValue": "2",
    "EnumValue": {
        "Name": "name",
        "SomeEnum": {"1": "option1", "2": "option2", "3": "option3"}
    }

    "SubQuestion": "A second question",
    "AnswerValue": "3",
    "EnumValue": {
        "Name": "name",
        "SomeEnum": {"1": "option1", "2": "option2", "3": "option3"}
    }

}
```

In the JSON I have some questions with answers.
The stucture of the JSON cannot be changed.

In my frontend there are checkboxes with the questions and answers (checked if AnswerValue == SomeEnum )

All enum values must be shown on the front end. 
The checkbox must be checked if AnswerValue == SomeEnum

The problem is if you use a repeat to loop trough the answers the enum list wil be dublicated if you have multiple answers (see below)

```
[ ] option1<br>
[x] option2<br>
[ ] option3<br>
[ ] option1<br>
[ ] option2<br>
[x] option3<br>
```

What I need is this:

```
[ ] option1<br>
[x] option2<br>
[X] option3<br>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, answer) in somevalue.EnumValue.SomeEnum">
    <div ng-if="key==somevalue.AnswerValue">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">{{answer}}<br>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="key!=somevalue.AnswerValue">
        <input type="checkbox">{{answer}}<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is a generic solution because the questions have different sets of enums values the sub questions (within one question) have the same set of enum values

Answer (score 0):

When using ng-repeat, you can use the **`unique`** filter to avoid duplicates:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, answer) in somevalue.EnumValue.SomeEnum | unique: 'answer'">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Unique works fine in one collection. 
But I need to compare 2 or more collections (from the sub-questions)